# Espresso : Recyclerview scroll to end

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

Is there a way to scroll to the end of recyclerview using Espresso?

There is an item with text let's say 'Text XYZ' and the recyclerview has an id recycler_view. This item happens to be the last item of the recycler view.

I tried

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo(withText("Text XYZ")),click());
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: doesn't seem to work - error log please

Comment: you are checking that view is displayed before scrolling to it.

Comment: @denys The ckeck is for the actual recyclerview. It should not make any difference unless the recyclerview is not actually displayed.

Comment: yes, makes sense.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo()` matches against the `ItemView` of the `ViewHolder`, which is inflated in `onCreateViewHolder()` of the adapter. And  in order for the `scrollTo()` to work, you need to provide a matcher that uniquely identifies that `ItemView`.

Your current matcher tells espresso to scroll to a ViewHolder that was inflated with a `TextView` as an `itemView`. Which can happen, but usually you have some `ViewGroup` action going on there to style the view holders in the way you want them to look.

If you change your `scrollTo()` Matcher, to `hasDescendant(withText("Text XYZ"))` to account for all nested layouts (if there more than one).

Also keep in mind since you are also trying to click the item - you can't do it in the same `perform()` because it will send the click to the current `ViewInteraction`, which is in this case a `RecyclerView` with id `R.id.recycler_view`. Doing so in the same perform just clicks the middle on the `RecyclerView`, not the item that you scrolled to.

To solve this you need either need another `onView()` with the matcher that you used to scroll to an item or use `RecyclerView.actionOnItem()`.

In case of another `onView()` statement, the `hasDescendant(withText("Text XYZ"))` will fail you, because it will find all parents of that TextView (viewholder, recyclerview, the viewgroup that holds the recyclerview and so on) as they all have this particular descendant. This will force you to make the `ItemView` matcher to be more precise and account for all nested layouts. My usual go to matcher is `withChild()` in these situations, but it might be different for you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, works perfectly! Should be smth like this   onView(withId(R.id.rvSettings)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo(hasDescendant(withText(stringId))));

Comment: onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions
                                 .scrollTo(hasDescendant(withText(getString(stringResId)))));
        onView(withText(getString(stringResId))).perform(click());

Answer (score 2):

If you know the last position of the `RecyclerView`, then you can scroll to it

```
static final int LAST_POSITION = 100;

// First method
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerview))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition((LAST_POSITION)));

// Second method
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerview))
        .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(LAST_POSITION, scrollTo()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if this approach doesn't show the scrolling up but allows you to select the position of the recycler.
Thanks to this guy ([Espresso-testing-recyclerviews](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/15/espresso-testing-recyclerviews/) I used this approach:

`onView(allOf(withId(R.id.recyclerUserCustomListsView)))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(7, click()));`